# Greek letters in chunk are not shown properly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have created an r chunk in an r markdown document, in which I have calculated some parameter values that I am required to find for a homework. Now I would like for my knitted PDF-document to show the sentence "Our estimate of $\beta_1$ is -0.2186". However, the portion of the code for the greek letter beta ($\beta_1$) is being shown in the PDF the same way it's written here, not as the actual greek letter.

I have already tried installing LaTeX-packages in the document header (e.g. \usepackage{mathtools}), which made no difference.

```
cigs_mean <- mean(smoke$cigs) #find y-bar
educ_mean <- mean(smoke$educ) #find x-bar
beta1_hat <- (cov(smoke$educ,smoke$cigs))/(var(smoke$educ)) #find beta1-hat
beta0_hat <- (cigs_mean-(beta1_hat*educ_mean)) #find beta0-hat

print(paste0("Our estimate of $\beta_1$ is ", round(beta1_hat, digits=4)))
```

I just want for the document to show a greek letter beta with subscript 1, rather than replicating the code I have written ($\beta_1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Backslashes in R character strings have a special meaning as escape characters](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html), and must themselves be escaped. Otherwise, your string `'$\beta$'` is read by R as `'$'` `‹backspace›` `'e'` `'t'` `'a'` `'$'`.

Furthermore, `print` is the wrong function to use here: its purpose is to provide output in the interactive R console, never for actual output to a document. Use `cat` instead.

Finally, if you haven’t already done so, you need to tell knitr to interpret the results of this code chunk as-is instead of rendering them as a result:

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
…
cat(paste0("Our estimate of $\\beta_1$ is ", round(beta1_hat, digits=4), "\n"))
```
````

Comment: After reading the provided link I do not quite understand how I should alter my code. When you say the backslashes themselves need to be escaped, should my code be the following?

cat(paste0("Our estimate of \\beta_1\ is ", round(beta1_hat, digits=4)))

(deleted the "$")

This gives me the output "Our estimate of \beta_1 is -0.2186", which is still not what I am looking for (the greek letter beta underscored with 0).

Sorry if I am being dense.

Comment: @Giämma You need to replace the sequence `'$\beta_1$'` with `'$\\beta_1$'`. The `$` signs denote this string as embedded LaTeX math code, so don’t delete those, otherwise the string will just be rendered directly, not interpreted as LaTeX math code.

Comment: The output now is "Our estimate of $\beta_1$ is -0.2186" - still no beta symbol. Perhaps the only way is to just write the sentences outside the R chunk as regular markdown syntax?

Comment: @Giämma I forgot to  mention, you also need to tell knitr/RMarkdown to print the result as-is instead of rendering it as a code chunk result. To do this, set the appropriate chunk option in the chunk header (see updated answer).